# Solr WordDelimiterFilter generate word parts and catenate in query

Tags: solr

I want query *wi-fi* to match documents with *wifi* in the index. So, I'm using *solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory* to catenate words in query:

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But using this configuration query *LGA1155* doesn't match *LGA 1155*, because query *title:LGA1155* is parsed as: *(title:lga title:1155 title:lga1155)~3*

If I don't catenate words in query, *LGA1155* matches *LGA 1155*, because query is parsed as: *(title:lga title:1155)~2*. But then *wi-fi* doesn't match *wifi*.

I'm using *edismax* query parser and *q.op* is *AND*. Solr version: 4.5.

So, how to make both *wi-fi* match *wifi* and *LGA1155* match *LGA 1155* (and other similar queries)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you describe it, you want to catenate word parts, but you want to split on numerics.

The `catenateAll="1"` you have in there is not good, as it will undo the split of numerics (*LGA115* becoming *LGA 1155*) you want to achieve.

Try it with these settings of the `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` in your analyzer.

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="0" catenateWords="1"
            generateNumberParts="1" catenateNumbers="0" splitOnNumerics="1"
            catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"
            stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="0" />
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This would produce the following tokens

- wi-fi -> `wifi`
- Wi-Fi -> `wifi`
- WiFi -> `wifi`
- LGA1155 -> `lga` `1155`
- LGA 1155 -> `lga` `1155`
- LGA-1155 -> `lga` `1155`

As you can see wifi becomes one word and LGA1155 gets separated.

---

Another thing is, as you can see in my sample, if the analyzer on query and index time shall be the same, as in your sample, you can leave out the `type` attribute in the `analyzer` element and delete one of the two elements completely.

So instead of

```xml
<fieldType ... >
    <analyzer type="query">
       <!-- same stuff -->
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
       <!-- same stuff -->
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Just

```xml
<fieldType ... >
    <analyzer>
       <!-- will be taken to index and query time -->
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

ICUFoldingFilterFactory does the job of LowerCaseFilterFactory.

Comment: Good hint, I hadn't the ICU running, and wasn't shure about it. I have removed the hint from the answer for googlers.